# Почему отличается время перебора объектов одного класса от множества классов?

Tags: javascript

Из-за ошибки возникла ситуация, которую очень хотелось бы понять.
Время на цикл (50 тыс итераций) перебора и обращение к свойствам экземпляров одного класса существенно отличается от времени перебора экземпляров разных классов. 2 мс против 40мс.

Возможно у кого нибудь будут мысли о причинах такого поведения.

Код:

```js
let length = 50000;

let list_of_one = [];
let main_class = getClass();

for(let i = 0; i<length;i++){
  list_of_one.push(new main_class()) 
}

let list_of_many = [];
for(let i = 0; i<length;i++){
  let main_class = getClass()
  list_of_many.push(new main_class())
}


performanceTest(list_of_one)  // результат ~2ms
performanceTest(list_of_many)  // результат ~40ms

function performanceTest(list){
 console.time('time')
  let c = list.length
  for(let i = 0; i<c;i++){
        list[i].buffer_data_calc.color[3] = i
  }
  console.timeEnd('time')
}


function getClass(){
 class Main {
   id=23;
   type= 1;
   buffer_data_calc={color:[1,2,3,4,5]};
   init(){

   }
 }
    return Main
}
```

p.s было замечено что уже на поиск свойства  buffer_data_calc уходит большая времени...

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinnic/smt8hwab/53/)

Comment: https://jsperf.com/iterating-over-same-class-vs-multiple-classes/1  кейс на jsPerf

Answer (score 2):

Есть 2 момента.

Когда функция работает с объектами одного и того же типа, она компилируется под этот тип. Количество одновременно существующих скомпилированных функций ограничено. Если тип оказывается разным, браузеру может понадобиться откуда-то что-то достать (скомпилировать функцию, достать альтернативный скомпилированный вариант или что-то ещё) и на это потребуется время. Вот, Илья Климов рассказывает [как добавление части объектов одного поля сказалось на производительности](https://youtu.be/ZAJmJmKWNPw).

И второй момент, касающийся именно приведённого примера. При доступе к свойствам есть обычный доступ, а есть доступ при котором уже известно, в каким сдвигом оно записано. Браузер старается в большинстве случаев использовать второй, поскольку он быстрее. Но в твоём массиве вообще все объекты разных классов - скорее всего при таком массиве браузер откажется от второго варианта и будет использовать первый. Если сократить число классов до 2 (или нескольких), то ситуация может измениться.

PS: Ответ полностью основан на моих предположениях и знаниях. Я не пытался компилировать и исследовать приведённый код, чтобы дать более детальный и/или точный ответ по нему.

PPS: Видео 2015 года, что-то могло уже и измениться. Но на конвертацию объектов из быстрого вида в словари я натыкался в прошлом году (пришлось фиксить - на словари просто памяти не хватало и страница валилась). Впрочем, именно словари к вопросу не относятся, поскольку в цикле нет модификации свойств.

Comment: И что же не то в моем ответе тогда?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, ответил под твоим ответом.

Comment: Не знаю как можно говорить об однородности по ссылкам когда я такого не имел ввиду в принципе.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ. "функция работает с объектами одного и того же типа, она компилируется под этот тип" - особенно эта часть

Comment: Какая разница движку на тип, когда он считывает свойства?

Comment: @AntonV, видео посмотри.

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы считаете что в цикле у вас одинаковые операции. Дело в том что в первом случае вы подготовили класс и в цикле добавляете новые экземпляры этого класса. Но во втором случае вы генерирует новый класс в цикле дополнительно, что не может не занимать время и только потом создаёте новый экземпляр класса. Проверьте на примере явно созданный 5-10 классов и добавьте их в цикле. Я не думаю что в этом будет существенная разница.

На счёт теста. У вас не однородный и однородный массивы. Понятно чтоб получить свойство в однородном будет быстрее нежели постоянно узнавать в различном.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что тест производительности в perfTest одинаковый для обоих вариантов

Comment: Антон это замыкание. И в первом случае вы вызываете замыкание а во втором создаёте новое и вызываете. Теперь по тесту. Каждый класс логично занимает в памяти место пройтись по 50 000 классам и по 1 му думаю простое переключение будет занимать время.

Comment: Это js он интерпретируется и каждый новый класс не экземпляр класса должен создаться отдельно в памяти.  А когда вы вызываете то нужно постоянно переключаться между ними

Comment: По другому если объяснить. У вас есть 50 000 одинаковых мешков и различных нужно узнать вместимость. Понятно что в первом случае это делается просто нежели во втором

Comment: Обновил код примера, так понимаю что list_of_one и list_of_many в  js в конечном счете, просто объекты, и performanceTest просто идет перебор обьектов, и обращение к свойству.

Comment: Именно так. Это для вас они похожие для машины они различные и нужно постоянно узнавать что по чем

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ivinnic/smt8hwab/65/ обратите внимание, добавил тест листание на списка простых объектов.

Comment: Да и он понятен. Не нужно бегать в класс чтоб узнать свойства объекта

Comment: В примере с мешками в третьем случае у вас на мешке написано сколь там и вам нужно тупо сложить

Comment: Что-то не то...

Comment: Ну если не то то удалю ответ.

Comment: @AzizUmarov 1. Ты пишешь про создание классов и объектов, но оно вне замера времени, так что влиять не должно. 2. Про однородный и неоднородный массив не очень понятно. Есть мнение, что однородный массив в принципе работает быстрее, чем неоднородный, но корректных доказательств этого факта я найти не смог. Обычно подтверждающие замеры были криво сделаны (если в сложение чисел закинуть строку, то очевидно, что конкатенация работает дольше сложения и это не проблема массива). К тому же, как правило массивы объектов считают однородными независимо от объектов, поскольку объекты - ссылочный тип.

Comment: 3. Само утверждение про более медленный доступ к свойству из-за разных объектов в массиве. Оно может быть верным, но меня смущает его категоричность. Я бы предположил, что если различных объектов будет немного, то такой проблемы не будет, но это надо замерять и оно совсем не очевидно.

Comment: Я к примеру что нужно замерять тож указал. И сказал использовать 5 10 классов для сравнения.

Comment: Однородность по ссылкам уже извините, если опускаться до этого то то пробежаться по ссылкам будет одно и то же время, а по свойствам то извините результат вам виден